# spriteBatch.draw is not getting overloaded

Tags: libgdx, android-studio

I am following [this](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/05/01/LibGDX-Tutorial-11-Tiled-Maps-Part-2-Adding-a-character-sprite.aspx) tutorial from gamefromscratch.com tutorial 11.
I am using **libGdx** framework in **Android studio** .

```
public class OrthogonalTiledMapRendererWithSprites extends OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer {

public OrthogonalTiledMapRendererWithSprites(TiledMap map) {
    super(map);
}

@Override
public void renderObject(MapObject object) {
    if(object instanceof TextureMapObject) {
        TextureMapObject textureObj = (TextureMapObject) object;
            spriteBatch.draw(textureObj.getTextureRegion(), textureObj.getX(), textureObj.getY()); // getting error in this line
    }
}
}
```

I am getting an unresolved error in the following line

```
spriteBatch.draw(textureObj.getTextureRegion(), textureObj.getX(), textureObj.getY());
```

The code in render() method is

```
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
    tiledMapRenderer.render();
    }
```

I am new in game development please help me solve this error.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that `spriteBatch` isn't available in the scope. The tutorial you've referenced uses `this.getSpriteBatch()` to get a `SpriteBatch` to use while rendering, but as the comments on the tutorial page point out, this method isn't available anymore.

Instead of `spriteBatch` or `getSpriteBatch()`, you have to use the more abstract version `getBatch()` which is inherited from `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer` which inherits the method actually from `BatchTiledMapRenderer`.

Comment: the code I am using doesn't consist of this.getSpriteBatch() . I have added the render() method in the question.
please help me in this

Comment: That doesn't change anything. `spriteBatch` isn't defined as I say in my answer.

Comment: I just defined spriteBatch and called spriteBatch.begin and spriteBatch.end and it worked , thanks .